# Redirecting request with file not working, Flask

Tags: python, flask

```
from flask import Flask, request, render_template, Response
import requests

app = Flask(__name__, template_folder='../templates')


@app.route('/', defaults={'path': ''}, methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@app.route('/<path:path>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index(path):
    headers = request.headers
    subdomain = headers['Host'].replace("mydomain.com", "")

    port_mapping = {
        '': 5001,
        'test.': 5002
    }

    if subdomain in port_mapping:
        new_port = port_mapping[subdomain]
        destination_url = f'http://127.0.0.1:{new_port}'

        if request.method == 'POST':
            response = requests.post(destination_url + request.full_path, headers=headers, data=request.form, files=request.files)
        else:
            response = requests.get(destination_url + request.full_path, headers=headers)

        return Response(response.content, status=response.status_code, headers=dict(response.headers))
    else:
        return render_template("/errors/subdomain_not_found.html")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='127.0.0.1', port=5000, debug=True)
```

I use this script to redirect requests to another port on my machine depending on the subdomain. This code works fine until I want to send a file. I can do "print(request.files)" in this piece of code and it would work fine, but when I try to do the same in the flask app on port 5002 it prints an empty ImmutableMultiDict instead of an ImmutableMultiDict with the file. This is how the code on port 5002 looks like.

```
@app.route('/upload', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def upload_file():
    print(request.files)

    if 'file' not in request.files:
        return 'No file part'
    file = request.files['file']
    if file.filename == '':
        return 'No selected file'
    # Save the file to a desired location
    file.save('uploads/' + file.filename)
    return 'File uploaded successfully'
```

Sending this curl request

```
curl --request POST \
  --url http://127.0.0.1:5002/upload \
  --header 'content-type: multipart/form-data' \
  --form 'file=@C:\Users\user\test\PIA23010.jpg'
```

Works perfectly, so the problem is probably at the redirect script.

UPDATE/EDIT:

I found out that the problem is in the headers that are being send by the redirect script. If I don't send the request.headers with the post request it works fine, but I don't have access to the things like ip or session. These are the headers anyone know what header could be the problem? I maybe should have said that I am using a [cloudflare CLI tunnel](https://developers.cloudflare.com/cloudflare-one/connections/connect-networks/get-started/create-local-tunnel/) to send all traffic of my domain to port 5000 on my machine. If need more info please ask me!

```
Host: test.mydomain.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/121.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
Content-Length: 539174
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.7
Accept-Encoding: gzip
Accept-Language: nl-NL,nl;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Cdn-Loop: cloudflare
Cf-Connecting-Ip: <my ip>
Cf-Ipcountry: NL
Cf-Ray: 854df8ce8b43655a-AMS
Cf-Visitor: {"scheme":"https"}
Cf-Warp-Tag-Id: 0fd09830-d7ac-4e03-8fd1-d8e9514007d9
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryWZgFuAYmKpBZIzzr
Cookie: session=.eJyrVjJyc1SySkvMKU7VUUrNTczMUbJSUtJRykxJzSvJTMtMTYHL5uSnp6em6GbmwUXyEnNTIcoLEouLy_OLUkC8WgCGjBsW.ZcuEpQ.OKkJMLdIH_tL9t-eUv2T-Sc_zWk
Origin: https://test.mydomain.com
Priority: u=0, i
Referer: https://test.mydomain.com/upload_page
Sec-Ch-Ua: "Not A(Brand";v="99", "Google Chrome";v="121", "Chromium";v="121"
Sec-Ch-Ua-Mobile: ?0
Sec-Ch-Ua-Platform: "Windows"
Sec-Fetch-Dest: document
Sec-Fetch-Mode: navigate
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin
Sec-Fetch-User: ?1
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
X-Forwarded-For: <my ip>
X-Forwarded-Proto: https
```

Comment: You're not redirecting to `/upload`.  What's in `request.full_path`?

Comment: @TimRoberts, request.full_path is the page path, so if I go to mydomain.com/upload, the request.full_path is /upload

Comment: You cannot directly pass a flask request.files object across to the requests library as a files parameter as, even though they have very similar names, they are completely different data structures internally. Should not be too hard to map one to the other though.

Comment: @EAW I am quite new to flask and Python in general, so what would you recommend me doing to map one to the other?

Comment: Your first @app.route does not require "/upload".